# How to update master detail in Entity Framework using Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, relationship

I'm trying to simulate update the child using AutoMapper. The relations are 1-to-many with "On Delete Cascade".

My steps:

1. Load the master with details included
2. Map the master to masterDTO
3. update/changes the details in masterDTO
4. Map back masterDTO to master
5. Save it.

The problem is : the master is updated,new details is added,. but the updated detail not **persistence**.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Master 
{
        public int id {get;set;}
        public string masterInfo {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Detail> details { get;set; } = new Collection<Detail>();
}

public class Detail 
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int masterId {get;set;}
    public virtual Master master {get;set;} 
    public string detailInfo {get;set;}
}

public class MasterDTO 
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string masterInfo {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DetailDTO> details { get; set;} = new Collection<DetailDTO>();
}

public class DetailDTO 
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int masterId {get;set;}
    public virtual MasterDTO master {get;set;} 
    public string detailInfo {get;set;}
}
```

The `DbContext` setup:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Master> Masters {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Detail> Details {get;set;}

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=localhost;Database=Test_AutoMapper;Trusted_Connection=True");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
                    .HasMany<Detail>(m => m.details)
                    .WithOne(d => d.master)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.masterId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

And here is `StartUp` program & Automapper setup:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<Master, MasterDTO>().ForMember(a => a.details, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.details));
            cfg.CreateMap<Detail, DetailDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<MasterDTO, Master>().ForMember(a => a.details, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.details));
            cfg.CreateMap<DetailDTO, Detail>();              
                });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var context = new MyContext();
        var master = context.Masters.Include(m => m.details).find(1);
             // there is master in db with id = 1

        var masterDTO = mapper.Map<Master, MasterDTO>(master);

        masterDTO.masterInfo = "Changed value";
        foreach (DetailDTO element in masterDTO.details) {
            element.detailInfo = "Changed value";
        }

        var newElement = new DetailDTO {id = 0,  masterId = 1, detailInfo="New Detail"};
        masterDTO.details.Add(newElement);

        master = mapper.Map(masterDTO, master);

        context.SaveChanges();

}
```

The last simulation I got this result

```
Before :                                After :
Master                                  Master
+----+-------------------+              +----+-------------------+   
| id | masterInfo        |              | id | masterInfo        |
+----+-------------------+              +----+-------------------+
| 1  | Old Master Info 1 |              | 1  | Changed value     |
| 2  | Old Master Info 2 |              | 2  | Old Master Info 2 |
+----+-------------------+              +----+-------------------+

Detail                                  Detail
+----+----------+-------------------+   +----+----------+-------------------+   
| id | masterId | detailInfo        |   | id | masterId | masterInfo        |
+----+----------+-------------------+   +----+----------+-------------------+
| 1  | 1        | Old Detail Info 1 |   | 1  | 1        | old Detail Info 1 |
| 2  | 1        | Old Detail Info 2 |   | 2  | 1        | Old Detail Info 2 |
|    |          |                   |   | 3  | 1        | New detail        | 
+----+----------+-------------------+   +----+----------+-------------------+
```

The 2 row of detials are **not updated**

Thanks for you advice. - Jigu

Answer (score 1):

When performing an update your code using mapper.Map is correct, however you need to remove these lines:

```
context.Masters.Add(master);
context.Entry(master).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Your context has loaded and is tracking the Master instance, so all you need to do is update the properties (which `Mapper.Map` is doing) then call `SaveChanges` on the context and EF will take care of the rest.

`Add` is used to add a new entity instance to the DbContext. Setting the state to `Modified` is only needed when attaching an instance to the DbContext. In your case the entity is already associated.

Usually this issue crops up when devs use the default mapper.Map call:

```
// Loads the entity which the Context will track, but then mapper.Map() returns a new instance in the reference. The context is still tracking the first reference.    
var master = context.Masters.Single(x => x.MasterId = masterDTO.MasterId);
master = mapper.Map<Master>(masterDTO);
```

This method creates a new Mapper entity with the properties which isn't associated with the context so they would use `Add`, `Update`, or `Attach`+`.State = EntitySate.Modified` to try and put it into the Context resulting in an error when the context was already tracking a matching entity.

Update: To enable change tracking through the related properties you need to mark your navigation properties as `virtual` to enable the proxies.

```
public class Master 
{
        public int id {get;set;}
        public string masterInfo {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Detail> details { get;set; } = new Collection<Detail>();
}

public class Detail 
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int masterId {get;set;}
    public virtual Master master {get;set;} 
    public string detailInfo {get;set;}
}
```

Update 2: A run down on update scenarios.

It looks like the confusion is based on mixing up concepts from the 2 main ways you can update entities in EF. Here is a quick breakdown of the 2 approaches:

Approach 1: With Tracking/Proxies. By default, EF DbContexts will track entities that they load using proxy wrappers. This allows related entities to be lazy loaded, but more importantly allows EF to detect when individual columns change to use in UPDATE statements. To use this approach, the navigation properties need to be marked as `virtual`, the DB context should be configured to auto-detect changes. (enabled by default) and queries should *not* use `AsNoTracking`. Using this approach is the simplest way to load data, make updates and save the changes. For Related entities that you want to update, use `Include` to eager load them.

```
var parent = context.Parents.Include(x => x.Children).Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
parent.PhoneNumber= "0456-7689";
foreach(var child in parent.Children)
{
   child.IsAttending = true;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

The advantages of this approach is that it is simple. No need to set modified state, attach to a context, or worry about duplicate entries. The disadvantage of this approach is when attempting to update large amounts of data. The more rows a DbContext is tracking, the longer reads and updates will take to resolve. Also, something as simple as accidentally adding an `AsNoTracking()` to a query or leaving a virtual off a navigation property will gunk up the behaviour.

Approach 2: Without tracking. Sometimes code that uses EF will want to work with detached entities. This can be because entities are being serialized back and forth to a client/consumer, or dealing with large numbers of entities, or simply a preferred (albeit complex) design decision by the development team. In this case the DbContext should not be tracking the instances, and those instances should be in a Detached state. So a simple example of this would be something like:

```
var parent = context.Parents.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Children.AsNoTracking()).Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
parent.PhoneNumber= "0456-7689";
foreach(var child in parent.Children)
{
   child.IsAttending = true;
}
```

Now in this case we cannot just call `context.SaveChanges()`. There won't be an error, but nothing will be saved because the context isn't tracking these entities or detecting changes.

We have to explicitly associate them back to the DbContext and set their modified state:

```
context.Attach(parent); // This will attach the parent, and the children, but in an Unmodified state.
context.Entity(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
foreach(var child in parent.Children)
{
   context.Entity(child).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
context.SaveChanges();
// In some cases we will want to detach the parent and children again here.
```

With this approach you need to be more deliberate with the re-association of entities to the DbContext. The trouble can come when the entity in question was deserialized or the context is fairly long-lived where it may have been already tracking an entity. In these cases the `Attach()` call may fail, so to be safe you should check that an entity isn't already tracked by the context. If the entity was passed into a method where you want to perform an update, you should also check that the entity isn't tracked by another DbContext.

For instance, given a method like below:

```
public void UpdateParentDetails(Parent parent)
{
    parent.PhoneNumber= "0456-7689";
    foreach(var child in parent.Children)
    {
       child.IsAttending = true;
    }
    _context.Attach(parent); 
    _context.Entity(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
    foreach(var child in parent.Children)
    {
       context.Entity(child).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Code like this can be prone to problems and misuse. Was the passed in parent associated with a Context already, with the same _context or another context instance? Does _context track another reference to this Parent? Were the Children eager loaded? Are any of the children tracked? What should we do in any of these cases?

At a minimum we should assert that the passed in parent wasn't null, wasn't associated to a DbContext, and check that we aren't already tracking the parent:

```
public void UpdateParentDetails(Parent parent)
{
    if (parent == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");

    if (parent.State != EntityState.Detached)
        throw new ArgumentException("Parent was associated to a DbContext");

    var existingParent = _context.Parents.Local.Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
    if (existingParent != null)
    {
        existingParent.PhoneNumber= "0456-7689";
        foreach(var child in existingParent.Children)
        {
           child.IsAttending = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        parent.PhoneNumber= "0456-7689";
        foreach(var child in parent.Children)
        {
           child.IsAttending = true;
        }
        _context.Attach(parent); 
        _context.Entity(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
        foreach(var child in parent.Children)
        {
           context.Entity(child).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see, this starts getting a fair bit more complicated to try and ensure that assumptions about an entity's state and whether a DbContext is tracking an instance. This is why I generally do not advise development teams to attempt to work with detached entities. The code/intention starts off reasonably simple but almost invariably starts to run into issues that lead to more code, more complexity, and more bugs.  For this reason I recommend that entities never get passed outside of the scope of the DbContext that they were read. Using DTOs or ViewModels is a much preferred approach to this and then using approach #1 above to load, update, and save the entity. The key there is to avoid mixing in elements from approach #2.

Comment: I just removed those lines.

Comment: The error is disappear, but changed details nor master not saved.

Comment: before and after the `mapper.Map(masterDto, master)` call can you check what the Modified state is on master? ( value of `context.Entry(master).State`)  It almost sounds like it is Detached, but your example doesn't point to it being. (I.e. using `AsNoTracking` or disabling proxies) AHHH.. You need to make the collection and back reference `virtual` Otherwise no change tracking. Editing answer

Comment: Also, be sure that a Master row exists when doing an update like this. If you know at least 1 record exists for this test, use `First` not `FirstOrDefault`. If no record exists then you will want to use `Add`, if a record is expected, load it, edit it and `SaveChanges`

Comment: Hi Steave,.. Yes i am sure have 1 record with id =1

Comment: I'm also put Console to write state,.. please see the main question, i put updated code there.. thanks

Comment: Ok, for this suggestion to work, you need to remove the `AsNoTracking` when loading the Master from the DbContext, and ensure that the related entities are declared as `virtual`.

Comment: I've updated the answer again to outline the two main update approaches which I think are getting intermixed within the answers and what you have been trying.

Comment: Hi Steve,. I really appreciate your help,. It make clear for me to solve the problem.. Thank you very much..

Comment: Hi Steve,. would you please review my code,. it's still give me an error... thanks

Comment: What error are you getting with the new code?  I'm not 100% sure what Automapper will do when it comes to a new DTO in the collection that isn't in the source. Admittedly in practice I use Automapper for Entity => ViewModel, not the other way.  This is a dated article, but might still be applicable for Automapper and limitations when mapping to Entity sets. https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need use `context.Masters.Add(master);`

and you should change the mapper config to

```cs
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Master, MasterDTO>().ForMember(a => a.details, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.details));
            cfg.CreateMap<Detail, DetailDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<MasterDTO, Master>().ForMember(a => a.details, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.details));
            cfg.CreateMap<DetailDTO, Detail>(); 
        });
```

then chack if entity is not tracked attach them to context and update entity

```cs
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var context = new MyContext();
var master = context.Masters.Include(m => m.details).FirstOrDefault();

var masterDTO = mapper.Map<Master, MasterDTO>(master);

masterDTO.masterInfo = "master - changed to new value";
foreach (DetailDTO element in masterDTO.details)
{
    element.detailInfo = "detail - changed to new value";
}

// try to add new element 
var newElement = new DetailDTO { id = 0, masterId = 1, detailInfo = "New Detail" };
masterDTO.details.Add(newElement);

Console.Write(context.Entry(master).State.ToString());  //--> Detached
master = mapper.Map(masterDTO, master);
Console.Write(context.Entry(master).State.ToString());  //--> Detached


if (context.Entry(master).State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    context.Masters.Attach(master);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes, the error is disappear, but changed data not saved.. ??? need more advice please. thank you

Comment: Hi Farhad, the changed value still not saved, when I debug. the master value already changed before line context.SaveChanges() execute.

Comment: @JiguJigu Hi :) break point reaches the line `context.Masters.Attach(master);` and `context.Details.Attach(item);` ?

Comment: the master & details already contain the updated value, but  context.Entry(item).State is unchange.

Comment: @JiguJigu do you mean `master.details` not changed after save changes?

Comment: and context.Entry(master).State is Detached

Comment: @JiguJigu do you use the updated answer? i updated the answer many times

Comment: Hi Farhad, Thank you for your help.  Yes I use updated code from you,. please see the main question,. I put updated code there.. And I need more advice..:(.

Comment: @JiguJigu i update my answer and it works successfully :). i removed `AsNoTracking()`. good luck :]